# DELL OEM logo is not shown on Ubuntu startup

Tags: dell, 20.04, startup, plymouth, logo

I have an HP 255 G4 laptop and DELL OptiPlex 790 USFF PC both with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. On the laptop, the HP logo is shown on startup, but the PC doesn't show DELL logo?! When I tried to update-alternatives for Plymouth I get the message that there is only one theme installed - the default one and there is nothing to be configured.

In `/etc/default/grub` I've `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` as default.

I want Dell logo to shows on startup but I'm out of suggestions on how to do it...

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in legacy mode?

Comment: can you run these commands `ls -la /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth`
`ls -la /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth`